# When is a NSTableColumn released?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I thought I would be clever and store the address of a C++ callback function that is strongly associated with each column in the NSTableColumn of its NSTableView.  I subclassed NSTableColumn, and added a pointer as instance data.  I implemented a subclassed -dealloc that destructs that pointer (and calls super dealloc, of course).

The problem is, it doesn't seem the derived NSTableColumn's -dealloc ever gets called when, for example when [myNSTableView removeTableColumn:theColumn] is called.  I'm guessing its a memory management issue -- maybe the NSTableColumn is autorelease?

I couldn't find any other delegate / notification for when the NSTableColumn is removed.  Must I subclass NSTableView's removeTableColumn just to intercept the column removal?

EDIT: Because some have wondered, this "pointer" is to an instance of a C++ class that was created from Boost's Signals2. It provides a signal/callback mechanism from a C++ model into an Objective-C++ method.  The pointer needs to be deleted, in order to remove the callback subscription from the model's broadcasting class.

EDIT2: Regarding the definition of theColumn, it is create as below and then added to the table:

MyNSTableColumn *theColumn = [[MyNSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:columnModelAsId];

And the code in question iterates through the table's columns, removing them:

```
while([[compareTableView tableColumns] count] > fromWhichColumn) {
    [compareTableView removeTableColumn:[[compareTableView tableColumns] lastObject]];
```

There is a SEPARATE variable definition in the interface of the :

```
IBOutlet NSTableColumn *myDocumentColumn;
```

...which is pointed to my subclass (MyNSTableColumn) in IB.

(NOTE: Cell-based table -- Mac OS)

Comment: iOS? C++? Your tags don't seem right

Comment: A pointer to a callback function doesn't need to be destroyed. Is it a functor (function-like object)? Also, why is important when it gets destroyed so long as it eventually does? If you suspect a leak, use the Leaks instrument to analyze which code over-retained or under-released it.

Comment: What's the declaration of `theColumn`? Is it a local variable or an instance variable? What's the line of code (if any) that sets it?

Comment: @KenThomases -- See my EDIT above.  If it doesn't get destroyed, then model messages continue to get sent to the NSTableColumn object when that object may or may not be in the table.

Comment: @JustSid -- I wish folks wouldn't assume my tags are wrong and edit them.  While I guess this may not focus on C++, I guess it may more correctly be Objective-C++, though the pointer in question is a genuine C++ object that contains the ID and SEL of an Objective-C++ class and method.  I add IOS because for the most part there's a huge overlap between Cocoa & Cocoa Touch -- and especially the skill set of those two groups of engineers.

Comment: Does the signal object retain its target? If so, then you have a circular reference keeping the column alive. Ideally, you'd use a weak reference from the signal object to its owning table column. Or you'd have a controller object which owned both the signal and the table column and disassociated them when it removed the column from the table. Put another way: why doesn't the code you show which removes the columns break that association?

Comment: @SMGreenfield And I wish to find a million dollar in my wallet every time I open it. Guess we just can't have nice things. As far as this question is concerned, it doesn't have anything to do with C++, the object you store is of no concern here. And it doesn't have to do anything with iOS either, no iOS developer will be able to help you here.

Comment: “a huge overlap between Cocoa and Cocoa Touch” doesn't make this an iOS question.

Comment: So, you created your column using `alloc` and `init`(`WithIdentifier:`). Where do you release or autorelease the column?

Comment: @PeterHosey -- THANKS -- This appears to be the problem -- I assumed that addTableColumn took possession of the column -- but I forgot that it does this by retaining the column object.  After calling addTableColumn, I now [theColumn release], and now it appears the dealloc is called when removeTableColumn is called.

I also get your point regarding IOS: perhaps my point should've been referring to similarities between AppKit and UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

This question was more properly answered by Peter Hosey (above), but I'll add a complete answer if others make the same mistake I did:

After creating an instance of my subclass of NSTableColumn:

```
MyNSTableColumn *theColumn = [[MyNSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:columnModelAsId];
```

...and adding it to my table:

```
[myTableView addTableColumn:theColumn];
```

I found that my subclass' dealloc method wasn't being called when removeTableColumn was being called.

The solution, as Peter pointed out above (and below), was that since I created the object, I MUST release it -- even though the NSTable took ownership/retained theColumn. So I needed to release it right after I added it:

```
[theColumn release];
```

Failing to do so was certainly a dumb mistake to make.  As Ken Thomases pointed out, the Leaks instrument would've caught and diagnosed the issue in short order.

Comment: Well, you need to release the column regardless of what the NSTableView is going to do; its own ownership means only that you have a choice to release the column immediately after adding it or within `dealloc`. What the NSTableView is going to do makes no difference to your own obligations; you need to release it entirely because you created it.

Comment: @PeterHosey -- I see that now.  I've edited the above answer to reflect your point.  BTW -- enjoyed your web site.